# Use RecyclerView to Hold Multiple Images Per Row

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How do I use RecyclerView to display multiple ImageView every row? For instance, to show images as 4X6 like iPhone Photos app.
Should I manually adjust ViewHolder to display a certain number of ImageView? Or is there a smarter way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use grid with RecylerView.

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recylerId);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, numberOfImagesInARow));
```

Comment: That makes sense, definitely gonna try it out later, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In order to display multiple ImageView every row you can use GridLayoutManager.
app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
app:spanCount="2"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GridLayoutManager` or `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` with `RecyclerView`, 
 to show multiple image on a single row.

```
// Using GridLayoutManager
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, numberOfColumns));

// Using StaggeredGridLayoutManager
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(numberOfColumns, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
```

See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html)

**Tutorials link:**

1. https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/12/android-recyclerview.html
2. https://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/